# How is the best way to add select with choices to filters in Sonata Admin?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How is the best way to add select with choices to filters in Sonata Admin?

For form i can:

```
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'),
    'required'  => false,
));
```

but this not working in filters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your admin class you should use [*`configureDatagridFilters`*](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#example) function to add your filters,if you want to add custom options for your `gender` fields you can use `doctrine_orm_string` and provide your choices list in array form

```
$datagridMapper
       ->add('gender',
        'doctrine_orm_string',
        array(), 
       'choice',
        array('choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female')
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{

    $datagridMapper

       ->add('gender',null,  array(), ChoiceType::class, array(
           'choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female')
       ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight which parts make the difference and why they help to solve the problem, such that others can learn from that snippet?

Answer (score 3):

On my version - symfony 3.4 and "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.0"

worked this way:

```
->add('preferredLanguage', 'doctrine_orm_choice', [
                    'global_search' => true,
                    'field_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                    'field_options' => [
                        'choices' => [
                            'English' => PotentialCustomerInterface::PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH,
                            'Spanish' => PotentialCustomerInterface::PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_SPANISH
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            )
```

The choices are string values in database.

If you want choices from database filtered by some logic:

```
    ->add('csr', 'doctrine_orm_choice', [
            'field_type' => EntityType::class,

            'field_options' => [
                'class' => User::class,
                'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $userRepository) {
                    return $userRepository->qbFindAdmins();
                },
            ]

        ]
    )
```

In UserRepository just create method which returns query builder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **symfony 4.3** and **sonata-admin-bundle 3.0** and this is how I ended up doing:

```
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\StringFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

/**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('gender', StringFilter::class, ['label' => 'Gender'], ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => ['m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female']
        ])
    ;
}
```